# Must be a date in the future: Instance of 'TZDateTime'

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a Notification Helper which schedules notifications. Everything works perfect but scheduling notifications does not work. I print the scheduled date, it is after DateTime.now() but still receiving that error:

```
E/flutter ( 9512): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument (scheduledDate): Must be a date in the future: Instance of 'TZDateTime'
```

This is my function:

```
 static Future<void> setNotification(
      DateTime dateTime, int id, String title, String body) async {
    var now = DateTime.now();
    Duration duration = dateTime.difference(now);
    print(dateTime.toString());
    print(dateTime.toUtc());
    print(" tz : ${tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(duration)}");
    print("tz local: ${tz.local}");
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      id,
      '$title',
      '$body',
      tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(duration),
      _notificationDetails,
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    );
  }
```

How can I convert DateTime to TZDateTime properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **FlutterLocalNotifications** package uses TimeZone sensitive DateTime, the **FlutterLocalNotifications** docs suggest us to use [TimeZone](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone) package
so to use it in your code first you must import it and initialize it

```
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
tz.initializeTimeZones();
```

then you must get the location using `zone = tz.getLocation('Africa/Algiers');`
note that *Africa/Algiers* is a timezone example

then you can simply get TZDateTime from DateTime like this

```
  tz.TZDateTime.from(DateTime.now(), zone),
```

**zone** is the location we got earlier

this will work like charm,